# Is it possible to fill a SQLalchemy foreign key in a model and have it load the related object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLAlchemy, I have a ***transactionlog*** model, that has a related ***member***. This relation is defined by a *tlog_ppl_id* column in the transactionlog table, that references a *ppl_id* column in a *people* table ( the *people* table contains *members*).

Suppose I have a new Transactionlog object T.
If I load a member-object (lets call it M), and set T.member = M, I can access T.member and it returns my linked member.

What I'd like to do is have my new transactionlog SQLAlchemy object T, and fill the tlog_ppl_id property with a valid ppl_id.
After I do that, I'd like to access T.member, and have SQLAlchemy load the related people record from the database. It does not do so however, it returns *None*.

So I wonder if it is possible to have SQLAlchemy load the related objects with a specific instruction, if I only fill the objects foreign key columns?

code to test this:

```
def test():
    from app.models.data import Transactionlog
    T = Transactionlog()
    T.tlog_ppl_id = '2433A992-B8C7-4780-91DE-67D12C517C55'
    print(T.member)
    return ""
```

code in the model:

```
class Transactionlog(transactionlog):
    """
    Transactionlog model class.
    """

    member = relationship("People", backref=backref('transactions'))
```

I'm using SQLalchemy 1.0.14 on Python 3.5.1 under flask (not using flask-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get SQLAlchemy to populate a relationship based on the current foreign key values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160775/can-i-get-sqlalchemy-to-populate-a-relationship-based-on-the-current-foreign-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you might be looking for [`load_on_pending`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.load_on_pending), though its use is discouraged:

> The `load_on_pending` flag does not improve behavior when the ORM is used normally - object references should be constructed at the object level, not at the foreign key level, so that they are present in an ordinary way before a flush proceeds. This flag is not not intended for general use.

Note that all in all in your `test` function the newly created `T` instance is not added to a session before attempting to print the related `People` instance, so it simply cannot do any loading (unless some magic is at play and all new model instances are added to some default session).

Here's a little demo of how you perhaps could use the `load_on_pending` option, though I think you really should just use the instance objects instead of the foreign keys:

```
In [8]: class A(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'a'
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

In [9]: class B(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = 'b'
   ...:     b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
   ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.a_id'))
   ...:     a = relationship('A', load_on_pending=True)

In [10]: class C(Base):
    ...:     __tablename__ = 'c'
    ...:     C_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ...:     a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.a_id'))
    ...:     a = relationship('A')

In [16]: session.add(A(a_id=1))

In [17]: session.commit()

In [18]: b = B()

In [19]: session.add(b)

In [20]: b.a_id = 1

In [21]: b.a
Out[21]: <__main__.A at 0x7ff32388ab70>

In [22]: session.rollback()

In [23]: c = C()

In [25]: session.add(c)

In [26]: c.a_id = 1

In [27]: c.a

In [28]: session.commit()

In [29]: c.a
Out[29]: <__main__.A at 0x7ff32388ab70>
```

But, as stated before, the recommended approach would be to use the instances, not the foreign keys:

```
# Will look the instance up in the session's identity map, if present
T.member = session.query(People).get('2433...')
```

I think that the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) applies in this case:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

I.e. explicitly query for the to-be-related object instead of relying on implicit lookup after setting the foreign key.

Comment: Thank you. This is right, we have changed the way we work with related objects to better match SQLalchemy's way of working.